# Adjusting date if date falls on a weekend or bank holiday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that inserts some new records into a table, myTbl from a temporary table, myTblTemp.

In the query I adjust one of the fields 'AnnDate' if the date is a Saturday or Sunday. However I also need to adjust the AnnDate if the date is a bank holiday.

I have a table, tblBankHoliday which lists all required up coming bank holidays. How do I adjust my query (or do I need a seperate one) that will add one day to the date if the AnnDate is found in the tblBankHoliday?

**My current query**

```
insert into myTbl(AnnDate, USDVal)
case DATENAME(WEEKDAY, AnnDate) 
       when 'Saturday' 
       then DATEADD(DD, 2, AnnDate) 
       when 'Sunday' 
       then DATEADD(DD, 1, AnnDate) 
       else AnnDate 
end
from myTblTemp
```

Comment: Rather than having a `tblBankHoliday`, have you considered having a more inclusive calendar table that lists *all* dates. You'll then usually end up with (either computed from other columns or directly stored) an "Is Working Day"-style column from which you can approach this problem in a *uniform* fashion, not trying to deal with weekends and bank holidays individually.

Comment: This might be a good start: [Bones of SQL - The Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table e.g. `thedays`. Insert all days from the relevant period in it. e.g. in a column `theday`. In another column e.g. `isworkday` mark workdays with 1 non workdays with 0.

Then you can select the next workday at or after a given day in you query.

```
insert into myTbl(AnnDate, USDVal)
(SELECT min(theday)
        FROM thedays
        WHERE theday >= AnnDate
              AND theday.isworkday = 1)
...
from myTblTemp
```

Answer (score 1):

***Sticky bit's answer is way better for your case.***

---

You can use a recursive CTE to cycle through non-valid dates and keep increasing by 1 day until your validation fulfills.

```
;WITH PatchedDates AS
(
    SELECT
        InitialAnnDate = C.AnnDate,
        CorrectedAnnDate = C.AnnDate,
        USDVal = C.USDVal,
        IsDateOK = CASE 
            WHEN 
                EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblBankHoliday AS X WHERE X.BankHoliday = C.AnnDate) OR 
                DATENAME(WEEKDAY, C.AnnDate) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'No' 
            ELSE 'Yes' END
    from 
        myTblTemp AS C
        LEFT JOIN tblBankHoliday AS T ON C.AnnDate = T.BankHoliday

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        InitialAnnDate = C.InitialAnnDate,
        CorrectedAnnDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.CorrectedAnnDate),
        USDVal = C.USDVal,
        IsDateOK = CASE 
            WHEN 
                EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblBankHoliday AS X WHERE X.BankHoliday = DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.CorrectedAnnDate)) OR 
                DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.CorrectedAnnDate)) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'No' 
            ELSE 'Yes' END
    FROM
        PatchedDates AS C
    WHERE
        C.IsDateOK = 'No'
)
insert into myTbl(
    AnnDate, 
    USDVal)
SELECT
    AnnDate = C.CorrectedAnnDate,
    USDVal = C.USDVal
FROM
    PatchedDates AS C
WHERE
    C.IsDateOK = 'Yes'
```